# Excel - i need to make the output value of a formula permanent even if the input is deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create something like the <kbd>M+</kbd> button on the calculator.

I want the output value of a formula not to be overwritten when I change or delete the input values but instead being used in the formula again with the new inputs. Hopefully this makes sense.

In other way I want the output value to be used with the new input values in the same formula (which is a simple addition formula).

Comment: For all intents and purposes, this is no different than a timestamp Worksheet_Change issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can do something sort of like this with VBA, though I don't think that you can without VBA (at least without using circular references, which have their own problems). The key is to use a static dictionary which retains memory of the state of each cell which contains the formula. Something like:

```
Function PlusM(x As Double) As Double
    Static states As Object, state As Double, key As String

    If states Is Nothing Then
        Set states = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If

    key = Application.Caller.Address

    If states.Exists(key) Then
        state = states(key)
    Else
        state = 0
        states.Add key, state
    End If

    state = state + x
    states(key) = state
    PlusM = state
End Function
```

If I put `=PlusM(A1)` in A2 when A1 is initially blank then A2 will display 0. If I enter any value in A1 then A2 will now display that value. If I then delete the value in A1, A2 will retain its value. If I then put a new value in A1, A2 will display its old value + new value from A1. The use of the dictionary allows different cells to have instances of `=PlusM()` without the state of one cell leaking into that of another.

It isn't the most robust solution -- loss of state is an issue. It won't retain its state if something resets the project (including closing and then reopening the workbook). I've experimented with replacing the line `state = 0` with `state = Application.Caller.Value` with mixed results. If this is an issue, doubtless something could be done woth `WorkBook_Open()` to restore state.